# Facebook JS SDK Does Not Set fbs_* Cookie in Safari

Tags: facebook, cookies, sdk, safari

I've read a few posts about how to fix this, to sum it up:

- Manually create the fbs_* cookie during the first POST request to your app
- Add a "Start App" link, when the user clicks it Safari lets you set cookies (http://lightyearsoftware.com/2009/11/on-the-pain-of-developing-for-facebook/)
- Create and submit a form client side (http://anantgarg.com/2010/02/18/cross-domain-cookies-in-safari/)

None of that seems to work, I'm questioning whether or not that information is still valid (I'm on Safari 5.0.5). I need to use the fbs cookie to properly authenticate the user on the server side, and this works on every other browser. I can't set any cookies on the initial POST request, and the client-side form submit doesn't work either. Does Safari not let you set third party cookies even on a POST anymore?

Answer (score 1):

The reason cookies are rejected is a default "third party cookies" policy in Safari.

To properly authenticate the user you better stay away from manual usage of fbs_* cookies placed by Facebook's JS (or any other) SDK and use [FB.getSession](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getSession/) / [FB.getAuthResponse](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/) and/or [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) from JS SDK. On the server side you can use [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter passed to all Canvas and Page Profile Tab applications.